# Does validation accuracy/loss impact training in caffe

Tags: validation, caffe

Have a simple question about validation set in caffe, was wondering if validation set has any impact on training? I know that you use validation set to check if the network isn't overfitting and as I understand validation set has no impact on weight update, but does it have some kind of impact on selecting or modifying hyper-parameters or is it just for user to see and estimate how well network has learned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the results of the validation set are not used by the neural network during training to adjust any hyperparameters. Using the validation set during training is the same as applying the network at some point in time to predict values for the validation set, and then scoring how well it did.

You might decide that you want to run the same network training procedure many times over using different values for hyperparameters. In its fully exhaustive form, that would mean you would do a grid search over the hyperparameter space with many different training sessions of separate networks. In practice, it's not a great idea to do a fully exhaustive grid search with neural networks because the amount of parameters can be extremely large.

Often with neural networks you can tune one parameter at a time until they each seem "about right". Of course this might not get you the absolute best result, but it's not a bad first approach.